# access singleton and inner classes each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, singleton, encapsulation

I'm kind of new to javascript. I'm so confused that javascript Objects!!

My code skeleton is bellow...

```
var jCanvas = new function(){
    this.init = function(canvasID){
        ...
    };

    var DrawingManager = new function(){
        drawInfos = [];   // DrawInfo objects will be pushed into this
        this.mouseState = MouseState.released;
        ...
    };

    function DrawInfo(bm, cl, id, x, y){
        ...
    }

    function Point(x, y){
        ...
    }

    var MouseState = new function(){
        ...
    };

    var Color = new function(){
        ...
    };

    var BrushMode = new function(){
        ...
    };
};
```

1. I want jCanvas to be singleton class Object.
2. in jCanvas object, there are many singleton classes such as DrawingManager, MouseState, Color, BrushMode. And 2 more classes which are not singleton classes(Point, DrawInfo)
3. What I want is that, in DrawingManager, I want to access other classes and singleton class objects.

Problem is browser gives error that "MouseState is undefined".

I think I'm too familiar with Java, C# etc... I want my program to have good structure but this javascript make me so confused and don't know how to make good design pattern..

Please help me out..

Comment: I think I explained wrong, or nobody understood my point. Anyway, answers are very helpful information. MY POINT IS that I want to access inner class from other inner class... that's my point..

Comment: There are no inner classes in JS. There are just variables that are in scope, or not. All of your variables seem to be in-scope. I suggest you write a minimal executable example that exhibits your error; or we can just guess (as I did).

Answer (score 2):

To declare functions, don't use the `new` keyword. Only use it when creating instances of objects.

In JavaScript, you can declare a "class" like this (the body of the function is the constructor):

```
function MyClass (arg1) { 
    this.myClassProperty = arg1;
}
```

And then instantiate it:

```
var myObj = new MyClass();
```

If you want to create a singleton, the best method is to use an immediately invoked function:

```
var MySingleton = (function() {
    var myPrivateFunction = function() { ... };
    var myExportedFunction = function() { ... };
    var myPrivateVar = 5;
    return {
       myExportedFunction: myExportedFunction
    };
})();
```

Here, you create an anonymous function and immediately run it. It is kind of a more advanced concept though.
Or you can simply create an object:

```
var MySingleton = {
    myProperty: 1,
    myFunction: function() { ... },
    ...
};
```

Comment: As I know, to make singleton, immediately invoked function is one other option but "new function()" is also one other correct way. I can't use anonymous function as I have a lot of member functions in class.

Comment: `new function` is not a common syntax in JS, so it's confusing and you should avoid it. You can make a simple object, like in my last example, and it should work for you. And an immediately invoked function can have member functions inside it, it's not a problem.

Comment: @Myeong-jaeKim The purpose of the anonymous function is just to create new scope, so you can hide local ("private") variables. It is still just creating an object (with many methods, if you so choose).

Comment: I've updated my singleton example to show how functions, private functions and private variables are made.

Comment: @mromnia Thank you very much. I didn't know that. I changed all of my code not to use "new function"

Comment: But still my problem is not solved. My problem is that when I tried to use MouseState Singleton class in DrawingManager Singleton class, compiler gives error that it can't find MouseState. How can I access other class from the other?

Comment: Well, you have a problem of ordering. If you use the immediately invoked function pattern, and either define methods with `function X(){}` (then they're hoisted to the top of the scope), or declare methods as `var x =`, but before you use them in an object, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton classes in JavaScript make no sense. Either make a constructor ("class" for Java people) to instantiate multiple objects, or make an *object*. There is no point in making a constructor that you will only ever use once, then have the code to sanity-check whether or not you actually do use it only once. Just make an object.

The reason for the error is probably (but I might be wrong, I'm guessing about the rest of your code) the misunderstanding between `var x = function ...` and `function name() ...` forms. To whit:

```js
var a = function() { console.log("a"); }
function b() { console.log("b"); }

a(); // a
b(); // b
c(); // c
d(); // TypeError: d is not a function

function c() { console.log("c"); }
var d = function() { console.log("d"); }
```

They are identical in effect, but they differ in whether they are hoisted to the top of the scope or not. `var d` is hoisted, just like `function c() { ... }` - so the variable `d` will exist, but will be `undefined`, since the assignment is not hoisted. Having both styles of function declarations is inconsistent unless you have a good reason for it; pick one of them and stick to it, is what I'd recommend.

Comment: I changed order of declaration but it still gives same error. I think it's not about the order.